# Iterating in a matrix avoiding loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I am posing an interesting and useful question that needs to be carried out in MATLAB. It is about efficiency of programming by avoiding using Loops"

Assume a matrix `URm` whose *columns* are **products** and *rows* are **people**. The matrix entries are **rating** of people to these products, and this matrix is *sparse* as each person normally rates only few products.

```
 URm  [n_u, n_i]
```

Another matrix of interest is `F`, which contains attribute for each of the products and the attribute is of fixed length:

```
 F  [n_f,n_i]
```

We divide the `URm` into two sub-matrices randomly: `URmTrain` and `URmTest` where the former is used for training the system and the latter for test. These two matrices have similar rows (users) but they could have different number of columns (products).

We can find the similarity between items very fast using `pdist()` or Matrix transpose:

```
 S = F * F' ;
```

For each row (user) in `URmTest`:

```
URmTestp = zeros(size(URmTest));
u = 1 ;   %% Example user 1

for i = 1 : size(URmTest,2)
indTrain = find(URmTrain(u,:)) ;   % For each user, search for items  in URmTrain that have been rated by the the user (i.e. the have a rating greater than zero)
  for j = 1 : length(indTrain)
    URmTestp(u,i) = URmTestp(u,i) + S(i,indTrain(j))*URmTrain(u,indTrain(j))
  end
end
```

where `URmp` is the predicted version of `URm` and we can compute an error on how good our prediction has been.

**Example**

Lets's make a simple example. Let's assume the items user 1 has rated items 3 , 5 and 17:

```
indTrain = [3 5 17]
```

For each item `j` in `URmTest`, I want to predict the rating using the following formula:

```
URmTestp(u,j) = S(j,3)*URmTrain(u,3) + S(j,5)*URmTrain(u,5) + S(j,17)*URmTrain(u,17)
```

Once completed this process needs to be repeated for all users.

As `URm` is typically very big, I prefer options which use least amount of 'loops'. We may be able to take advantage of `bsxfun` but I am not sure if we can.

Please suggest me ides that can help on  accelerating this process as rapid as possible. Thank you

Comment: I suggest that you add a working loop-based example, that would explain it much more clearly what you wish to achieve.

Comment: Andras, thanks for your comment. If we can answer this question more than 50% of the problem is solved. Just consider the example I gave, where indTrain is variable length but indTest is of length 1. Can we write the prediction formula avoiding loop?

Comment: I might have been a bit passive-agressive with my previous comment. Here's the direct version: I have no idea what you're exactly trying to do. I'd gladly vectorize it for you, but for that you need to specify your problem in clear terms. As far as programming questions go, *code* is as clear as it gets.

Comment: Getting better:) If `s_ij` is in fact dependent on `i` and `j`, then put it in the inner loop as `s_ij = F(:,indTest(i)) .* F(:,indTrain(j))`.

Comment: Andreas please find a loop example edited in my question

Comment: Also, I suspect that every `URmp(u,i)` should in fact be `URmp(u,indTest(i))`.

Comment: Sure we can do that but beware that by using 'pdist' we can compute the similarity between all products in less than a second and use it in the iteration. No need to compute it online !

Comment: Ah, sorry the indexing was edited, thank you

Comment: Your last definition of `s_ij` is a vector. Do you mean to transpose the first vector, giving you a scalar product? And did you mean `URm_19 = s_93*URm_13 + s_95*URm_53+s_917*URm_117`?

Comment: OK, I'm lost. Once it's `URm`, then it's `URmp`. You're using only `URmp` in your looping code, but only `URm` in your anecdotal example. Are these two things? And how is it that `URm_19 = s_93*URm_13 + s_95*URm_53+s_917*URm_117`? What is `URm` before this operation? I suggest you correcting *every* indexing issue and typo in your example, before we can move on.

Comment: Thank you Andras. I have modified the original question to answer your comment. In `URmTestp` the letter `p` stands for prediction, i.e. the predicted version of rating.  Hope the situation is more clarified now please let me know if I can provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure I completely understand your problem. But it seems to me that if you pre-compute `s_ij` as

```
s_ij = F.' * F   %'// [ni x ni] matrix
```

then what you're after is simply

```
URmTestp(u,indTest) = URmTrain(u,indTrain) * s_ij(indTrain,indTest);
% or
%URmTestp(u,:) = URmTrain(u,indTrain) * s_ij(indTrain,:);
```

or if you only compute a smaller `s_ij` block only for the necessary arrays,

```
s_ij = F(:,indTrain).' * F(:,indTest);
```

then

```
URmTestp(u,indTest) = URmTrain(u,indTrain) * s_ij;
```

Alternatively, you can always compute the necessary subblock of `s_ij` on the fly:

```
URmTestp(u,indTest) = URmTrainp(u,indTrain) * F(:,indTrain).'*F(:,indTest);
```

If I understand correctly that `indTest` and `indTrain` are functions of `u`, such as

```
URmTestp = zeros(n_u,n_i);  %// pre-allocate here!
for u=1:n_u
    indTest = testCell{u};
    indTrain = trainCell{u};
    URmTestp(u,indTest) = URmTrainp(u,indTrain) * F(:,indTrain).'*F(:,indTest); %'
    ...
end
```

then probably not much can be vectorized on this loop, unless there's a *very* tricky indexing scheme that allows you to use linear indices. I'd stick with this setup.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please kindly find my revised question according to your comments. Likewise you can revise your reply to meet the original question to have a clear discussion. With this, can we avoid the loop I have written?

Comment: @Yas I've updated my answer. Let me know if I misunderstood, I'm still not sure I understand your problem correctly:)

Comment: It is not exaclty what I asked for, but your respond contains yseful information. Thanks Andras ! The problem is solved for now